# MVC Controller State Managment

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on Webhooks Concept. Since Webhooks acts like a trigger, it will be firing an event when Update or Insert takes place.
It's a MVC application and I have two Controllers, Home and Webhook Controller.
I am passing arguments through Query String on Home  controller.
I have tried Session, TempData and Cookies for passing variable from home to Webhooks

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", Request.Query["UserName"].ToString());
```

and getting session value on webhook controller

```
HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
```

Also tried the same for TempData

Issue is On webbooks Controller its coming null.

I need to store parameter (User Name ,password)  and reuse the same for database related operations.

Kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you store the data into the cookie, session or TempData, it will always use the cookie. But you said the Webhook should worked as a trigger.

I guess this trigger is not triggered by the request or not. It was triggered by some application method. Since it doesn't contain the cookie ID which is used to get the session, cookie, TempData value.

I suggest you could use some database to store it, for example Redis, Service Bus.

If your data volume is not very large, I suggest you could consider using the memory cache, by using this , you could store these things into the memory and use it.

Notice: If your data is very large, I suggest you could use redis or service bus instead.

Comment: Thnaks Brado for the reply, Webhooks are basically  is a method of augmenting or altering the behavior of a web page or web application with custom callbacks.
In xero Whenever the contact is edoted or inserted in xero.com webhook get fired. 
Webhook listener in created in MVC as API.
I have tried session cookies and viewbag to transfer the data from one controller to another. Nothing is working pal. We need to store some credentila related information so that we can integrate the api. Kindy guide